# Mapping a texture with OpenGL using SOIL

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, texture2d, soil

Trying to complete a basic texture map to surface using OpenGL and SOIL but I am not generating anything.

```
GLuint textureID[5];

glutInitWindowPosition(0, 50);
windowID[0] = glutCreateWindow("orthogonal projection, cubes");

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-400, 400, -400, 400, -500, 500);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
glutDisplayFunc(DrawWindowOne);

textureID[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("assets/faceA.png", 
              SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);

void DrawWindowOne()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);   
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    glViewport(0, 0, 250, 250); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // front face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);     glVertex3f(-a,-a, a);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);     glVertex3f(-a, a, a);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);     glVertex3f( a, a, a);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);     glVertex3f( a,-a, a);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

The face draws in blue, however, and I get no texture. I have a second window, where apart from position the only differance is that I am using Frustrum as opposed to Orthogonal

```
windowID[1] = glutCreateWindow("Perspective projection using glFrustum");

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-60, 60, -60, 60, 60, 200);
gluLookAt(0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

and the texture draws fine.

Comment: Presumably the texture load and polygon draw are in different places in the code. Where does the former occur? I.e., after you make a context? Does `glGetError` say anything?

Comment: I have a window initilisation and then i grab the texture directly after, the rest is sequential in a draw function. I am going to put up the window code as when i enable my second window, the texture renders (that is, I can see it calling the same function in window 2, but I need it to display in window 1)

Comment: Hmmmm, at this point maybe an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as a pastebin link would be useful? I don't use SOIL or GLUT, but from what I recall this looks correct. Have a +1 for effort.

Comment: You should bind the texture before making the `glTexParameteri()` calls. I don't know if the SOIL function you call keeps the texture bound after it loads it.

Comment: just to confirm, if this was my problem, I would not be having any texture map. I have window 2 draw perfectly. Textures. Depth control. etc. But window 1 draws it all in solid blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was loading the textures all at once, where it appears they need to be loaded after each window is initialized to be available for that windows draw code.

```
#pragma region Initialise Window One
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 50);
windowID[1] = glutCreateWindow("orthogonal projection, cubes");
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-400, 400, -400, 400, -500, 500);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
glutDisplayFunc(DrawWindowOne);
LoadTextures();
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Initialise Window Two
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 450);
windowID[1] = glutCreateWindow("Perspective projection using glFrustum, ellipsoids");

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-60, 60, -60, 60, 60, 200);
gluLookAt(0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
glutDisplayFunc(DrawWindowTwo);
LoadTextures();
#pragma endregion
```